# how to generate xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need to be able to generate the following XML from a SQL table.
attribute name is the name of the columns in the table or query.

```
<case>
    <caseProperties>
        <property name="URErbName">xxx</property>
    </caseProperties>
    <caseData>
        <entity type="case" name="1" />
        <entity type="life" name="1" parentEntity="case_1">
            <attribute name="RISK_TYPES" value="LIFE" />
            <attribute name="AGE" value="45" />
            <attribute name="GENDER" value="Male" />
            <attribute name="BMI" value="30" />
            <attribute name="DIAB_INSULIN_INJECTION" value="Yes" />
            <attribute name="DIAB_NO_FURTHER_TREATMENT" value="Yes" />
            <attribute name="DIAB_PREGNANT_CURRENT" value="No" />
            <attribute name="DIAB_RECENT_HBA1C_READING" value="7.1 - 7.5%" />
            <attribute name="DIAB_TIME_CONDITION_DIAGNOSED" value="6 - 15 years ago" />
            <attribute name="DIAB_TWO_YEARS_HOSPITAL" value="No" />
            <attribute name="DIABETES_GLU_INTOL_HBS" value="No" />
            <attribute name="DIABETES_HBA1C" value="Yes" />
            <attribute name="DIABETES_OTHER_COMPLICATIONS" value="No" />
            <attribute name="GESTATIONAL_DIABETES" value="No" />
            <attribute name="DISCLOSURES" value="Diabetes" />
        </entity>
    </caseData>
</case>
```

Comment: Looks like you may have left something out?

Comment: <case>
<caseProperties>
        <property name="URErbName">xxx</property>
    </caseProperties>
    <caseData>
        <entity type="case" name="1" />
        <entity type="life" name="1" parentEntity="case_1">
            <attribute name="RISK_TYPES" value="LIFE"/>
            <attribute name="AGE" value="45"/>
            <attribute name="GENDER" value="Male"/>
            <attribute name="BMI" value="30"/>
                   </entity>
    </caseData>
</case

Comment: added the sample xml

Comment: do not comment , but edit your question please.

Comment: i am new to the site not sure how to post xml

Comment: Is this data coming from just one table? It doesn't look so... Please add more information about your source table(s). Add sample data. Best was a [mcve]

Comment: yes data is coming from one table

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
select * from table1 FOR XML AUTO
```

if this does not work for you. you can use more customized way

```
SELECT 
   UrErbName as "case/caseProperties/property",
   ...
FROM Customers
FOR XML PATH('Customer')
```

check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-auto-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017) for further information.

Comment: you need to make your own search. we cannot give you exact answer. we have jobs to do. I just would lıke to poınt you to right direction.